# Where is start_debug_demo.launch？

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am practising this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Debugging%20tf2%20problems

step by step:

$ roscd turtle_tf2            (:/opt/ros/melodic/share/turtle_tf2$ )
$ rosmake                          (done sth......)
  $ roslaunch start_debug_demo.launch

RLException: [start_debug_demo.launch] is not a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Where is start_debug_demo.launch？
I searched for "start_debug_demo.launch",and i only find it in my download package "geometry_tutorials-kinetic-devel", and it doesn't exist in the turtle_tf2 folder,but in the turtle_tf folder.
If i didn't download this package, there isn't the file"start_debug_demo.launch".

I didn't know how to do now?

Can you help me to analysis it?

Thank you very much for my so many questions maybe so simple,so stupid,i just want to learn ROS & ROS2 completely.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351251/where-is-start_debug_demo.launch%EF%BC%9F/) by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deleted this directory and did it again,and it works.
Close this question.

---

Originally posted by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) with karma: 17 on 2020-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raso](https://answers.ros.org/users/57564/raso/) on 2020-08-10**:
I have the same issue. Could you please provide more details?

Which directory did you delete? Which steps you did again?

Thank you.

**Comment by [CelestialPo](https://answers.ros.org/users/141988/celestialpo/) on 2023-03-15**:
Maybe it's because the launch file is in the directory /turtle_tf instead of /turtle_tf2.